# Does Azure Artifacts store the deltas of Universal Packages?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I'm already familiar with Azure Artifacts, and lately I've been trying to optimize billing expenses. Since Azure Artifacts charges per/GB, I've been wanting to know, does the Universal Packages feature attempt to optimize storage usage by only storing the differences between one version of the package and the next version of the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the Universal Packages feature attempt to optimize storage usage by only storing the differences between one version of the package and the next version of the package?

Agree with Jonathan. ***Customers are billed for the full size of each artifact stored on the service***

That **because** Azure Artifacts could not intelligently extract deltas from your package version 2 (*Sometimes we only modify the contents of the file.*) unless we only package deltas when we pack the package. But in this case, this deltas package should be another package instead of package version 2 (*It does not contain files from package version 1.*).

On the other hand, when we use the package version 2, we still could use the package 1  independently. Azure Artifacts still provides services for package version 1, so it is reasonable to pay for it. If you do not want to billed for the full size of each artifact stored on the service, you could delete the package version 1 after upload the package version 2.

Note: Every organization can use up to 2 GB storage for free. Additional storage usage is charged according to tiered rates starting at $2 per GB and decreasing to $0.25 per GB:

Rate card

- 0 - 2 GB = Free
- 2 - 10 GB = $2 per GB
- 10 - 100 GB = $1 per GB
- 100 - 1,000 GB = $0.50 per GB
- 1,000+ GB = $0.25 per GB

So, if your package does not exceed the GB boundary, there will be no additional charges.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Customers are billed for the full size of each artifact stored on the service, regardless of how we physically store it.

Comment: So if I have version 1 of package Foo, at 32MB, and version 2 of Foo is 33MB and the theoretical difference size is ~1MB, I will still be paying for 65MB of storage?